# Java, StaX simple code but get parse error, premature end of file

Tags: java, xml, eof, stax, malformed

I'm trying to figure out IO using StaX, but I keep getting "malformed" and "premature EOF" errors from the reader.  This is reading code created using StaX, as in the following example.

I've boiled down my code to the simplest configuration, and still get an error.  Where is this coming from?

SSCCE (should throw error)

```
package XMLTest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;

public class SaveLoadTest {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String FILE = "test.xml";

        //////////// WRITE
        final XMLOutputFactory OFACT = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        final XMLEventFactory EFACT = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        final XMLEventWriter WRITER = OFACT.createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream(FILE));

        WRITER.add(EFACT.createStartDocument());
        WRITER.add(EFACT.createComment("As basic as it gets."));
        WRITER.add(EFACT.createEndDocument());
        WRITER.close();

        //////////// READ
        final XMLInputFactory IFACT = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        final XMLEventReader READER = IFACT.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(FILE));

        while (READER.hasNext()) {
            READER.nextEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

And the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,49]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:85)
    at XMLTest.SaveLoadTest.main(SaveLoadTest.java:34)
```

I've had a look at several other SO questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976602/error-while-parsing-xml-file-with-stax) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580715/parsing-an-xml-response-from-a-url-using-stax) seem most relevant) but I'm having trouble relating them to this situation...

*EDIT*

Also, I have tried this reading and writing in separate operations, and the same thing happens.

*EDIT THE SECOND*

XML output file, as requested.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!--As basic as it gets.-->
```

Comment: Please post your input xml as well.

Comment: No input XML, it's made on the fly - I just want to create a header, create a comment, close the document, and then later read it.

Comment: That's the one I mean. test.xml should be available in your filesystem.

Comment: Can you print out the value of READER.nextEvent()?

Comment: @AmitBhargava - Oh, OK, yep updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's expecting the XML file to have a root element.

If your output code is changed to create an element it works:

```
    WRITER.add(EFACT.createStartDocument());
    WRITER.add(EFACT.createStartElement("", "", "element"));
    WRITER.add(EFACT.createEndElement("", "", "element"));
    WRITER.add(EFACT.createEndDocument());
```

Outputs into the file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><element></element>
```

And then reads the first event with no errors.

Comment: Ahh, so it does.  Thanks!  I've got a bad feeling about this though, there's some more headaches ahead for sure. :)

Comment: Headache update: none!  Figured everything else out pretty quickly after this small hiccup.  Best wishes to future StaXers.